# How to find the point on a hypotenuse divinging triangle into two right triangles?

Tags: mathematics, trigonometry

Consider the following image:

[image]

Knowing the (x,y) coordinates of A, B, and C; how would one find the point D? D being the point where line CD cuts the triangle into two smaller right triangles?

I feel like this is elementary, but searching for this is just giving me formulas to find the length of the lines, not the point I am trying to find.

EDIT:

Someone asked before deleting their post if this is a right triangle. Well; it COULD be, but not necessarily.

I should clarify why I need this. I have a quadratic bezier curve, and I want to find this point D on the triangle created by the 3 points (start, end, and control) of the bezier curve. I ultimately intend to check the angles formed by line CD at point C to restrict the "sharpness" of the curve (for road creation)

Comment: Hint: you can describe the line CD as starting at C and going in the direction perpendicular to AB.  Then, you find where the line CD intersects AB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find the slope of the line from A to B, then find the perpendicular slope. Lastly, find where the lines intersect.

The trick is that this is not actually a real triangle problem. Instead, you are trying to find the point on a line that is closest to another point (point C). The point on the line that is closest to the point will /always/ be perpendicular to the line, so yeah. Here's a tutorial on that if you're still confused: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFSdyike7g8

Next time, I believe this would go in the "Mathematics" stack exchange forum.

Comment: I actually tried to post this to that stack exchange first, but I do not have the required reputation to post the image :X

Comment: Also, this works! thank you for helping to re-frame the question. Thinking of it along these lines helped me to find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Oh. Odd. Well there is always the option of an ascii art maker xD jk anyway, welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

No trigonometry is necessary; just a little vector geometry and linear algebra.

Adopt the convention that \$\vec v\$ represents a 2D vector.

Then define two new vectors:

\$\vec c\ = \vec C - \vec A\$  *(with coordinates \$c_1\$ and \$c_2\$)*
\$\vec b\ = \vec B - \vec A\$  *(with coordinates \$b_1\$ and \$b_2\$)*

Now considering parameterized equations of:

- the line segment  \$\overline{CD}\$ in terms of \$t\$; and
- the line segment \$\overline{AB}\$ in terms of \$s\$

yields the following affine matrix equation for the intersection point, \$D\$, of the two lines:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & t & c_1\\
-t & 0 & c_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} 
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1\\b_2\\1
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
s\cdot b_1\\s\cdot b_2\\1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Solving for the scalar \$s\$ gives:

\$s=(c_1\cdot b_1 - c_2\cdot b_2) / ( (b_1 - b_2) (b_1 + b_2) )\$

The vector formula for \$\vec D\$ is then simply:

\$\vec D=\vec A+s(\vec B-\vec A)\$

Answer (score 0):

I figure that there's a really efficient way of computing this but I don't have it in my knowledge, but I'll do my best.

> ΔXYC is a triangle with vertices on points X, Y and C
>
> VW is a line which starts ands ends in points W and V
>
> ^PQR is the angle on point Q that comes and goes to points P and R

Triangles ABC and CDB are congruent, so the scale (Original/Copy) is AB/CB:

> We can calculate the length of CD by using the equation :
>
> AC / AB = **CD** / CB
>
> So **CD** = (AC * CB) / AB

And

^DCB = **^CAB**

> To know the angle you can just use law of sines; (Remeber that SIN((90°)) = 1)
>
> [ SIN(**^CAB**) ] / CB = [SIN (90°)] / AB
>
> SIN(**^CAB**) = CB * 1 / AB = CB / AB

Now you got your polar coordinates of point D **:D**

now you just need to convert from polar to Cartesian. Best of luck.

Comment: See my answer for a calculation without any trigonometry or polar coordinates.